# Why are some Javascript properties not displayed interactively in the debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, properties

Why are some Javascript object properties not displayed interactively in the debugger?

I have a complex object "albums".  If, in the Chrome debugger, I do:

> **console.dir(albums)**

I get an empty object (expanding it shows nothing).

Likewise, if I do

> **albums**

I get nothing.  However, suspecting that it does contain elements, if I ask for a specific property, e.g.,

> **albums["5146219665061590173"]**

I get the various properties belonging to this complex object.  Likewise, if I do console.log(JSON.stringify(albums)), I get a full definition of all the nested objects belonging to this object.

The semantics here are unclear to me; why do some object properties not show up?    (I thought my Javascript program wasn't working when I ran it in the debugger with strategically placed breakpoints, but now I see that the values are there, they just weren't always showing.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using cosole.log() instead of console.dir()?

Answer (score 2):

The console fetches the object's state when you expand it to show properties, if the properties have been removed after the `console.log/dir` they don't show up.

Try this:

```
console.dir(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(albums)));
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I don't how the properties would have been removed?

Comment: @MWood Are they removed when you log a clone using `console.dir(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(albums)));`?

Comment: Yes, they are.  The expression "albums" gives me nothing; the expression "JSON.stringify(albums)" shows the properties.  The expression "console.dir(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(albums))" shows an empty object. (I see also that it then shows in Chrome the line "< undefined" ...  don't see that if I just use the expression "albums".  Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: @MWood there is some dark magic going on if `JSON.stringify` gives proper result but `JSON.parse(JSON.stringigy(obj))` doesn't. Does the empty object logged have `.__proto__`?

Comment: No.  I didn't define a prototype, and in fact I am using albums as a dynamic dictionary (the keys are Facebook object ids).

Comment: @MWood no but if you even write `console.dir({})` you'll always get a `.__proto__`. [Try it](http://i.imgur.com/YqzIO.png). If you don't see that I think you have something going on with your chrome dev tools rather than your code.